# Select Dropbox value and appear at next text field

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

This is JavaScript

```
        function validation(form)
        {

            if(form.memt.value == "select"){
                document.getElementById("f").value = document.getElementById("t").value;
                form.memt.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
                form.name.style.backgroundColor = "";
                form.ic_1.style.backgroundColor = "";
                form.phone.style.backgroundColor = "";
                form.address.style.backgroundColor = "";
                form.memt.focus();
                alert("Please Select Your Member Type");
                pause;
            }
            if(form.name.value == ""){
                form.memt.style.backgroundColor = "";
                form.name.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
                form.ic_1.style.backgroundColor = "";
                form.phone.style.backgroundColor = "";
                form.address.style.backgroundColor = "";
                form.name.focus();
                alert("You Need Specify Your Name");
                pause;
            }
            var alphabert = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
            if(!form.name.value.match(alphabert))
                {
                    form.memt.style.backgroundColor = "";
                    form.name.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    form.ic_1.style.backgroundColor = "";
                    form.phone.style.backgroundColor = "";
                    form.address.style.backgroundColor = "";
                    form.name.focus();
                    document.getElementById("n").select();
                    alert("Name Must Be In Alphabert Form.");
                    pause;    
                }
               if(form.name.value == "G"){
               form.fees.value =="100"; <--- Problems Here
           }
            else{
                form.submit();
            }   
        }     
    </script>
```

Html

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend><strong><font color="White"> Create Member </font></strong></legend>
    <form action="AddMember"  >
    <table cellspacing="10">

    <tr>
        <!--  generating ID number  -->

        <td style="width: 200px" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="White" ><label>Member ID</label></font>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>

   <!--Selecting MemberType-->
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="White" ><label>Member Type</label></font>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4"><select name="memt" id="t" style="width: 290px">
                <option value="select">Select Member Type</option>
                <option value="N">Normal Member</option>
                <option value="S">Silver Member</option>
                <option value="G">Gold   Member</option></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!--MemberType Fees-->
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="White" ><label>Member Fees</label></font>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4"><input type="text" id="f" name="fees" style="width: 290px"  placeholder="Member Fee" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" style="width: 74px ; background-color:transparent ;color:white" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Add" style="width: 74px ; background-color:transparent ;color:white" onclick="validation(this.form); "/></td>
    </tr>

      </table>
    </form>
```

I Am now doing a dropbox option for Membertype,In the Option have 3 type of member,When i select the memberType For gold Member ,i want the Fee appear at next input text.
So how i going to solve this problem? Example,i select gold member,the membertype fees will auto come out 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the `change` event on the `<select>` element.

For displaying the fees, do not use a disabled textbox. Use `<span>` instead. Its more semantic.

**EDIT:** Span replaced with textbox.

**EDIT1:** Integrated previous snippet in the main code.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
function validation(form)
{

  if(form.memt.value == "select"){
    document.getElementById("f").value = document.getElementById("t").value;
    form.memt.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
    form.name.style.backgroundColor = "";
    form.ic_1.style.backgroundColor = "";
    form.phone.style.backgroundColor = "";
    form.address.style.backgroundColor = "";
    form.memt.focus();
    alert("Please Select Your Member Type");
    pause;
  }
  if(form.name.value == ""){
    form.memt.style.backgroundColor = "";
    form.name.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
    form.ic_1.style.backgroundColor = "";
    form.phone.style.backgroundColor = "";
    form.address.style.backgroundColor = "";
    form.name.focus();
    alert("You Need Specify Your Name");
    pause;
  }
  var alphabert = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
  if(!form.name.value.match(alphabert))
  {
    form.memt.style.backgroundColor = "";
    form.name.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    form.ic_1.style.backgroundColor = "";
    form.phone.style.backgroundColor = "";
    form.address.style.backgroundColor = "";
    form.name.focus();
    document.getElementById("n").select();
    alert("Name Must Be In Alphabert Form.");
    pause;    
  }
  else{
    form.submit();
  }   
}     

document.getElementById('t').addEventListener('change', function(){
  switch(this.value){
    case "N":
      document.getElementById('f').value = "10";
      break;
    case "S":
      document.getElementById('f').value = "20";
      break;
    case "G":
      document.getElementById('f').value = "30";
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById('f').value = "";
      break;

  }
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend><strong> Create Member </strong></legend>
  <form action="AddMember"  >
    <table cellspacing="10">

      <tr>
        <!--  generating ID number  -->

        <td style="width: 200px" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>Member ID</label>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4"></td>
      </tr>

      <!--Selecting MemberType-->
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>Member Type</label>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4"><select name="memt" id="t" style="width: 290px">
          <option value="select">Select Member Type</option>
          <option value="N">Normal Member</option>
          <option value="S">Silver Member</option>
          <option value="G">Gold   Member</option></select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!--MemberType Fees-->
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>Member Fees</label>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4"><input type="text" id="f" name="fees" style="width: 290px"  placeholder="Member Fee" readonly/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" style="width: 74px"  /></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Add" style="width: 74px " onclick="validation(this.form); "/></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>
```

[change | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

[switch | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: But i need add the value to database, input text needed?

Comment: @XiaoZhe Please checkout the updated code and working demo. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @XiaoZhe I have updated it to have a placeholder and ID same as in your code.

Comment: @XiaoZhe That's correct. Sorry I didnt mention that earlier. I have updated your code in my answer.

Comment: i done it,i just cut the javascript and paste below the fieldset,then can run already.thx you

Answer (score 0):

your select element will need an onchange attribute which will be a function in your javascript assigning the appropriate value to the 'f' input element

```
<select id="memt" onchange="onMemtChange" ... </select>

function onMemtChange() {
    document.getElementById('f').value=100
}
```

Comment: Can u check 1 more time,i make the code shorter just now.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#t').change(function(){

    $('#f').val("100");

});
```

Comment: Can u check 1 more time,i make the code shorter just now.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. Is this kind of thing worth a downvote? really?

Comment: That is not downvote by me,i just have 0 reputation.

Comment: No problem, it was for @Think Different